# Label parallel to draw

Tags: draw

How to make the label on the way of the draw?

Currently, my label "cross" the draws.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,
                backgrounds, bending,
                calc, chains,
                %decorations.pathmorphing,
                fit,
                %petri,
                positioning,
                trees,
                quotes,
                shapes.misc}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{31,22,70}
\definecolor{darkblue2}{RGB}{21,126,251}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (b) at (current page.center);
        \node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,rounded corners,draw=white, fill=darkblue2!50,very thick,font=\sffamily\color{white}]at(b)(MQTT){MQTT};        
        \node[label={[name=1]above:\Large{Orchestrateur}},left=2 cm of MQTT](admin){\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-b}};
        \node[label={[name=1]above:\Large{Edge Node 1}},above right=of MQTT](node1){\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-b}};
        
        \node [label={[name=1]below:deviceTwin}]at(node1)(dt1){\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{example-image-a}};
        \node [label={[name=1]below:\Large{Edge Node 2}},below right=of MQTT](node2){\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-a}};
        \node [label={[name=1]below:deviceTwin}]at(node2)(dt2){\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{example-image-a}};
        \draw[arrows={-triangle 90}, darkblue, thick](admin)--node[above]{Publish}(MQTT);
        \draw[arrows={triangle 90-triangle 90}, darkblue, thick](MQTT)--node[above]{Publish/Subscribe}(dt1);

        \draw[arrows={triangle 90-triangle 90}, darkblue, thick](MQTT)--node[above]{Publish/Subscribe}(dt2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
     \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the output[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the `sloped`option ? see : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260755/add-sloped-labels-in-tikz

Comment: Thanks, it works :)

Comment: Glad to hear it ! So i've converted my comment in an answer :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `sloped` seems to be what you are looking for. See a related [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260755/add-sloped-labels-in-tikz), you can simply use :

```
node[above, sloped] {Publish/Subscribe}
```

Your code with the applying options :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,
                backgrounds, bending,
                calc, chains,
                %decorations.pathmorphing,
                fit,
                %petri,
                positioning,
                trees,
                quotes,
                shapes.misc}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{31,22,70}
\definecolor{darkblue2}{RGB}{21,126,251}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (b) at (current page.center);
        \node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,rounded corners,draw=white, fill=darkblue2!50,very thick,font=\sffamily\color{white}]at(b)(MQTT){MQTT};        
        \node[label={[name=1]above:\Large{Orchestrateur}},left=2 cm of MQTT](admin){\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-b}};
        \node[label={[name=1]above:\Large{Edge Node 1}},above right=of MQTT](node1){\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-b}};

        \node [label={[name=1]below:deviceTwin}]at(node1)(dt1){\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{example-image-a}};
        \node [label={[name=1]below:\Large{Edge Node 2}},below right=of MQTT](node2){\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-a}};
        \node [label={[name=1]below:deviceTwin}]at(node2)(dt2){\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{example-image-a}};
        \draw[arrows={-triangle 90}, darkblue, thick](admin)--node[above]{Publish}(MQTT);
        \draw[arrows={triangle 90-triangle 90}, darkblue, thick](MQTT)--node[above, sloped]{Publish/Subscribe}(dt1);

        \draw[arrows={triangle 90-triangle 90}, darkblue, thick](MQTT)--node[above, sloped]{Publish/Subscribe}(dt2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
     \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the corresponding output  :

[image: Output]

Comment: My sincere compliments for your nice answer and for your contribute.